# Are there links between different stack exchanges?

Tags: feature-request

I have noticed that many of the questions asked here are relevant to other stack exchanges (mathematics or physics). My question is whether the Chem SE includes suggestions to other Stack exchange questions when asking questions or searching questions. If not, would including such feature be feasible? Furthermore if it is, do you think it would it be useful or do you think it would just clutter the site? Or do you think letting people link to the appropriate links as needed will be enough?

Comment: There have been some related efforts by our own Manishearth, see [this MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration) post for details on a similar concept.

Comment: From a practical perspective, I think it would be somewhat difficult to implement this in the UI, but I don't know that for sure.  Taste in interdisciplinary questions may differ from person to person, too.